# Use method arguments inside class definition (Ruby)

Tags: ruby, metaprogramming

I am attempting to add a method to all objects which allows adding variables to instances on the fly. However, I have run into the issue that when I begin the `class` block, the method arguments are out of scope and thus no longer available.

How might I access the method arguments from within the `class` block? Or is there a better way to do this?

```
class Object
    def addvar(name, value = nil)
        puts name # => "test"
        class << self
            puts name # => returns nil!
            attr_accessor name # => nil is not a symbol nor a string (TypeError)
        end
        self.instance_variable_set("@" + name.to_s, value)
    end
end

x = Object.new
x.addvar("test", 3)
```

It's also possible to use eval with string substitution, but that's something I would rather avoid for security reasons:

```
class Object
    def addvar(name, value = nil)
        eval("class << self
                  attr_accessor :#{name}
             end
             self.#{name} = #{value}")
    end
end

x = Object.new
x.addvar(:test, 3)
puts x.test
```

Comment: Why do you want to add variables on the fly? What do you try to achieve?

Comment: The use I thought of would be for mods in games; rather than having to mess with the underlying classes (possibly breaking inter-mod compatibility), modders can instead directly add properties to instances.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might need the [`instance_variable_set`](https://apidock.com/ruby/Object/instance_variable_set),  [`instance_variable_get`](https://apidock.com/ruby/Object/instance_variable_get), and other methods for metaprogramming in Ruby. Honestly, this is what `attr_accessor` uses under the hood.

The following code adds a singleton method to the object you call the `add_var` method on by using [`define_singleton_method`](https://apidock.com/ruby/Object/define_singleton_method):

```
class Object
  def addvar(name, value = nil)
    instance_name = "@#{name}"

    instance_variable_set(instance_name, value)

    define_singleton_method(name) do
      instance_variable_get(instance_name)
    end

    define_singleton_method("#{name}=") do |new_value|
      instance_variable_set(instance_name, new_value)
    end
  end
end

x = Object.new
x.addvar("test1", 3)
p x.test1

p Object.new.test1

=> 3
=> 1.rb:20:in `<main>': undefined method `test1' for #<Object:0x007fc98b161e10> (NoMethodError)
```

If you want to declare the method for any object of the class, you can use  [`define_method`](https://apidock.com/ruby/Module/define_method) on the class:

```
class Object
  def addvar(name, value = nil)
    instance_name = "@#{name}"

    instance_variable_set(instance_name, value)

    self.class.send(:define_method, name) do
      instance_variable_get(instance_name)
    end

    self.class.send(:define_method, "#{name}=") do |new_value|
      instance_variable_set(instance_name, new_value)
    end
  end
end

x = Object.new
x.addvar("test1", 3)
p x.test1

p Object.new.test1

=> 3
=> nil
```

By the way, you still can use `attr_accessor`, you can just call it on the class object:

```
class Object
  def addvar(name, value = nil)
    instance_variable_set("@#{name}", value)

    self.class.send(:attr_accessor, name)
  end
end

x = Object.new
x.addvar("test1", 3)
p x.test1

x.test1 = 5
p x.test1

p Object.new.test1
```

Comment: This adds a get method, but what about a set method? Ideally, one would only need to use `addvar` once, and then can use the syntax `x.test1 = 5`.

Comment: Great! I also noticed that you can also use `self.singleton_class` instead of `self.class` in your last example, and it will not add the property to all objects.

Comment: In general, `class << self` is not often needed. Always better to use the singleton methods if possible